# What online tools are available to investigate and classify solar eruptions?

Tags: the-sun, solar-flare, coronal-mass-ejection

I was just casually browsing when I came across a link about at recent solar flare. So I went to investigate at [SpaceWeather](https://www.spaceweather.com/). There it was stated:

[image]

Looking further down the page it seem to say that there is only a 5% chance for being an *X-flare*.

[image]

With other words, quite unlikely, while using a somewhat obtuse language of *"if current trends continue...could be..."*.

So my question is:

(a) **How are these flares tracked after they've been detected?**
(b) **What other detector mechanisms do we have (if any) along the way, to detect the progress of such CME's?**
(Preferably before they arrive here.)

---

Possibly related questions:

- [how accurate are the predictions for coronal mass ejections-(location, timing and magnitude)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27086/how-accurate-are-the-predictions-for-coronal-mass-ejections-location-timing-an)
- [What are the main differences between solar flares and coronal mass ejections?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/87/what-are-the-main-differences-between-solar-flares-and-coronal-mass-ejections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How are these flares tracked after they've been detected?

Since you already linked to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/16786/13663, I won't belabor the differences between a [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) and [coronal mass ejection (CME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection).  I will say that flares are short-lived phenomenon so they aren't really tracked so much as observed and their properties recorded.

They are observed by spacecraft such as the [GOES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_Operational_Environmental_Satellite) spacecraft x-ray detectors or the UV detectors on [SDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Dynamics_Observatory).

> What other detector mechanisms do we have (if any) along the way, to detect the progress of such CME's?

We have remote radio sensors onboard spacecraft like [Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_(spacecraft)) and [STEREO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEREO) that detect some types of radio bursts generated upstream of the shocks produced by CMEs.  We have particle detectors on these spacecraft and others that can observe the shock-accelerated particles before the CME arrives at Earth.  We also have [Parker Solar Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe) and [Solar Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Orbiter) that are closer to the Sun than Earth.  These are rarely on the Earth-Sun line, however, and their data are not telemetered to ground in real-time.  So they mostly provide after-the-fact observations of such phenomena.

Comment: Thank you, accepted. However, it seem that we have some serious holes in regard to any implemented warning systems, so I suppose we're lucky that our sun is still fairly well behaved.

Comment: I agree, but I am not in charge of funding so I have no control over that ;)

Comment: There's also [DSCOVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Climate_Observatory), that is located at L1 which would give us about 1 hr advance notice on CME's, according to that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Links to DSCOVR tools can be found [here](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/real-time-solar-wind) and [here](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/dscovr-schedule-tracking).

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of DSCOVR as I work with its mission scientist and was officemates with the guy who calibrates the magnetometer and am good friends with the guy in charge of the Faraday cups.  Unfortunately, I also know that DSCOVR suffers from a lot of problems.  These largely result from it having "sat on mothballs" for a decade and then received minimal funding for retrofitting and updating before launch.

Comment: As an aside, a really strong CME will get to Earth from L1 much faster than 1 hour and even when everything works perfectly, it still takes several minutes between the spacecraft observing something and a scientist or forecaster actually seeing the data on their screen.